# Storing application configuration settings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best place to store application configuration settings in AngularJS? This could be things like application constants, lookups etc. which could be used both from controllers and services or factories. I could create a separate service that stores and retrieves these things but I was wondering if there is another proper place to store and retrieve those.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the [constant()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) provider!

```
app.constant('myAppConfig', {ver: '1.2.2', bananas: 6, hammocks: 3, bananaHammocks: true});
```

This is not a whole lot different from Terry's solution, but constants don't change so they are applied before the other providers. Also, this module can be injected into your config function.

```
app.config(function(myAppConfig){
    console.log(myAppConfig.bananaHammocks);
});
```

have fun

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Yes, I was wondering if there was anything specific for this.

Comment: bannanaHammocks... HA!!

Comment: just for info, you **can change** the values **inside the** constant, if the constant is **an object**, like in the example above. Read more [here](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/)

Comment: I believe we have to inject it for the provided example.
`app.config('myAppConfig', function(myAppConfig){
    console.log(myAppConfig.bananaHammocks);
});`, otherwise you have 'uncaught error: [$injector:modulerr]' in a console.

Answer (score 14):

Not sure if there is a "best way" but I personally use a service, here is an abbreviated example:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AppSettings', function() {
  return {
    language: 'en'
  }
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['AppSettings', 
  function(AppSettings) {
    $scope.language = AppSettings.language;
  }
]);
```

Comment: Hi terry, I'm a total angular noob. I have my myApp.js. I assume that goes in there, but I'm not sure I'd get the setting. How would I get the value of language?. Thanks Mark

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `provider` instead of `service` and easy use everywhere.

```
angular.module('App', []).provider('config',
function() {
    var conf = {
        ver: '1.2.2',
        bananas: 6,
        hammocks: 3,
        bananaHammocks: true,
        baseUrl:'data/'
    };

    conf.$get = function () {
        delete conf.$get;
        return conf;
    };

    return conf;
});
```

Then use in config as `configProvider`:

```
angular.module('App').config( function(configProvider) {} );
```

In run, controllers, services, ect as `config`:

```
angular.module('App').run( function(config) {} );
```

Here is an example [link](http://embed.plnkr.co/7Ta8GO/preview) and of [code](http://embed.plnkr.co/7Ta8GO/app.js)

Answer (score 1):

Define:

```
angular.module('starter.config', [])
.constant('appConfig', {
  'backend': 'http://localhost:3000/v1'
});
```

Usage:

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['starter.config'])

.factory('Locations', function(appConfig, $http) {
  return {
    all: function(successCb, errorCb) {
      $http.get(appConfig.backend + '/locations.json')
      .success(successCb)
      .error(errorCb);
    },
    get: function(locationId, successCb, errorCb) {
      $http.get(appConfig.backend + '/locations/'+ locationId +'.json')
      .success(successCb)
      .error(errorCb);
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: so every time you need some setting you need to send http request and/or store what you got somewhere else? seems really inefficient

Answer (score -2):

Add this to have access to a global variable

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.globalVariable = 'Amadou'; //global variable
});
```

Now if you want to use it from your controller

```
function appNameCtrl($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.globalVariable = 'Modji';
}
```

In you view

```
My name is {{globalVariable}}
```

Comment: Any sort of globals should be avoided, especially when they are variables. Configurations are constants.

Comment: Why should configurations be constant? What if I have a language configuration that I want to be applied to all api calls to a certain endpoint?

Comment: @mameluc Then use services, not global variables.