# Different settings for debug/local ("grunt serve") vs. dist/build ("grunt")?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, settings, release

I want to define some [application settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17456989/storing-application-configuration-settings-in-angularjs), but I want to provide different values depending on whether I'm running in 'debug' mode (e.g. `grunt serve`), or whether the final compiled app is running (e.g. the output of `grunt`). That is, something like:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('AppSettings', function() {
  if (DebugMode()) { // ?? 
    return { apiPort: 12345 };
  } else {
    return { apiPort: 8008 };
  } 
});
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option

Comment: [This](http://newtriks.com/2013/11/29/environment-specific-configuration-in-angularjs-using-grunt/) seems promising but like way too much overkill for the simplicity of what I want to do ...

Comment: @allcaps: That seems to apply to options accessible from within grunt, but I'm looking to make an option accessible from within the final, distributed app

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle it in my apps:

1. move all your config data for one environment to a file: config.js, config.json,... whatever your app finds easy to read.
2. now modify your config file to turn it into a template using grunt config values, and generate the file with `grunt-template` as part of your build - for example: `app.constant('myAppConfig', {bananaHammocks: <%= banana.hammocks %>});`
3. finally, add `grunt-stage` to switch grunt config values depending on environment: create your different `config/secret/(env).json` files, update your template (`app.constant('myAppConfig', {bananaHammocks: <%= stg.banana.hammocks %>});`), and then `grunt stage:local:build` or `grunt stage:prod:build`

I find this the good balance between complexity and features (separation between environments, runtime code not concerned with building options,...)